# Help context tagging Qt with slickedit

Tags: qt, slickedit

I am trying to get Slickedit working with the Qt framework so that I can navigate the codebase easily and because of the other features it provides. To context tag the library I go to Tools > Tag Files, then I right click on C/C++ to add tag file. I name it Qt.vtg and then select the following trees:

```
C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\src
C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\include
```

I get context tagging for something, but I can't get context tagging for some scenarios where I normally get it:

When I try to get the parameters for a second pointer, it shows nothing:

```
oldAddress = ui->addressText->
```

When I try to complete specific headers it also gives no help

`#include <QtCore/ >`

I don't know if I am missing a step for context tagging QT, or the additional steps for context tagging QT.

Ted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to provide the include directories of QT for your project, either in your project's properties (Menu Project, Project properties, directories' tab), or in your compiler's properties (Menu Tools, Options, search for "Compiler properties"). This will enable your project to find the include files; the tag file alone doesn't really help, since you may have conflicting tags in the many tag files you could have, so the include files are necessary.
2. Make sure you have activated all the macros QT provides to your build system. It's been ten years since I used Qt, but IIRC there were several macro defines optionally specified on a compiler command line; make sure SlickEdit knows about them. (Menu Project, Project properties, compile/link tab).

If that's not sufficient, please give more details (where the definition is contained, settings for autocomplete, for context tagging, etc).